# Eclipse no "Design" pane?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, eclipse-plugin

Basically the issue is, that I no longer have a design tab in Eclipse. This issue appeared just now, when I was about to very happily work on some stuff.

I already had Swing Designer installed, and I've been working in the Design pane for a whole week. But today when I opened up Eclipse, it gave me some weird error that apparently the file was not found or the directory was missing, even thought it was right there on the screen and I could literally go to the workspace folder where the files were. So I had to delete the workspace and create a new one.

Trust me, I've been searching this issue for literally an hour, and every single time, the solution is right-clicking the .java file, and opening it with "WindowBuilder Editor". I've literally done this exact thing over 20 times, and no "Design" or "Source" panes on the bottom are appearing.

I've tried reinstalling the plugin, opening both the java and class files with "WindowBuilder Editor". Absolutely nothing works.

Comment: Found the solution. Had to put the .java file in the "src" folder. I don't know why, but somehow that worked.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Thanks trashgod. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Had to put the .java file in the "src" folder.